# How do I know the names of the sorted array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have four arrays A,B.C, and D. For example:
// example code is here: length of a is 1 length of b is 4 length of c is 1 length of d is 2.

```
var a = [1];
var b = [2,3,4,5];
var c = [6];
var d = [7,8];
```

I want to order those four arrays based on the larger length of the arrays, and I also want the names of the arrays those are in the sorted order. so the output will be:
names of the sorted array are b,d,a,c.

Comment: And how would they be sorted?

Comment: Sorted based on the length. So the final result will be [2,3,4,5, 7,8,1,6] and I also need the names of the child arrays those are b,d,a,c. So that I know which child arrays came first in the final result array.

Comment: No, I was asking how YOU were sorting them? What code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
var arr  = {}
arr["a"] = [1];
arr["b"] = [2,3,4,5];
arr["c"] = [6];
arr["d"] = [7,8];

Object.keys(arr).sort(function(a, b){ return arr[a].length < arr[b].length;  });
```

I did it way trying to keep the independence of the variables and closer to your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment says you want both the list of input array names and an array resulting from concatenating the input arrays together, in order.  You can get both in one step:

```
var [keys, array] = let (
    all = [["a", a], ["b", b], ["c", c], ["d", d]]
        .sort(function (a, b) { return a[1].length < b[1].length })
) [
    all.map(function (x) { return x[0] }),
    all.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b[1]) }, [])
];
```

Using your data, `keys` will contain `["b", "d", "a", "c"]` and `array` will contain `[2,3,4,5,7,8,1,6]`.